# How to insert one HTML element inside another?

Tags: javascript

There is a function:

```
function mapBuilder(container, props) {
    var map = document.createElement('app-map');
    document.getElementById(container).innerHTML += map;
    return map;
}
```

Using is:

```
  <div id="map"></div>
     <script src="map.js"></script>
        <script>
            mapBuilder('map', {sidebar: true});
        </script>
```

Why after execution line `document.getElementById(container).innerHTML += map;` I get the text `[object HTMLElement]` on the page instead of real HTML element?

Comment: The `.innerHTML` property is for adding HTML text content, so your newly-created element is being converted to a string value. You can use `.appendChild()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML. This method inserts some HTML to a certain place in DOM. You can also use .appendChild().

Answer (score 3):

map is a node element, not a string with HTML, so in this case you should use `appendChild()`

```
document.getElementById(container).appendChild(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append, use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
If you want to place before a child element, use [`ChildNode.before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/before)
If you want to place after a child element, use [`ChildNode.after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after)